# How to call autocomplete select event from outside the function

Tags: autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I have a location search form that uses jQuery UI autocomplete.

When the user starts typing into the input, our list of locations appear as a drop down menu just below the input. If the user clicks one of the locations, the page redirects to the landing page for that location. The user can also click "enter" on the keyboard instead of explicitly clicking on the item.

**Here's the probelm.** I can't figure out how to get autocomplete to work if the user clicks the SUBMIT button. I'm not allowed to simply remove the submit button because it's a "call to action". The markup & code look like this: (I'm writing this from memory, so it may not be exact)

```
<form id="locationSearch">
    <input type="text" id="enterLocation" />
    <input id="goButton "type="submit" value="GO" />
</form>


<script>

    var locations = [<br />
        {'value': 'Brooklyn', 'url': '/ny/brooklyn/browse'}
        { 'value' : 'Hoboken; , 'url' : /nj/hoboken/browse'}
    ];

    $('#enterLocation').autocomplete({
        autoFocus: true,
        source: 'locations',
        select: event, ui (function() {
            window.location.url
       });
    });

</script>
```

What I need to do is something like this:

```
$('#goButton').click(function() {
    // trigger automcomplete select
});
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
$('#enterLocation').trigger("autocompleteselect", function(){});
```